# Can EPOLLHUP trigger an event for a descriptor, disabled by EPOLLONESHOT?

Tags: c, multithreading, epoll

I have a few threads, waiting on the same `epoll_fd` with `epoll_wait()`. The descriptors within epoll set are setup in this way:

```
struct epoll_event event;
event.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLONESHOT;
event.data.fd = fd;
```

The purpose of `EPOLLONESHOT` is to guarantee, that each descriptor is handled only in one thread at the same time. If one thread has received `EPOLLIN` event with specific `fd`, can the `EPOLLHUP` or `EPOLLERR` trigger event in another thread with the same `fd`?

I suggest they can't - since the descriptor is disabled due to `EPOLLONESHOT`. But if they can - can I use `EPOLLRDHUP` instead? Will it be triggered **at least once** when the descriptor becomes invalid/closed/disconnected by any means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like disabled descriptors don't receive `EPOLLHUP`.